# Import from Access .accdb file to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import

How to import data from Access `.accdb` file to SQL Server? What should I choose in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard?

[image]

Suppose we choose OLE DB Provider for SQL Server Integration Services, then if that is a correct direction, what should be choose next from the following window? What to type in fields `Data Source` and `Location`, which mean more or less the same?

[image]

I followed instructions described here:
[Easiest way to import access db (.accdb) into SQL Server 2016?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/160794/67708)
I have installed `Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable`

However I was hopeless in seeing `Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLEDB`

**Update**

If I choose Data Source as `Microsoft Access (Microsoft Access Database Engine)` I end up getting error message the one shown on picture below. Moreover I think that this data source is tailored for files **mdb**, not **accdb**. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had to import Access files into SQL Server before and haven't found the Import and Export wizard to be a very good tool for the job. What I ended up doing was opening up the Access file, finding the table, right clicking and going to Export -> ODBC Database. This does require you to have a [User or System DSN](https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/41081) setup for the target SQL Server database, and it is a bit slow, but it was the only thing that I found that worked all that well. (It will create the target table for you.)

Answer (score 2):

Normally an Access Database file is protected with the `Admin` account and no password.

### Solution

Enter `Admin` into the **User name:** field and leave the **Password:** field empty. This should work.

Comment: No it doesn't work: Unrecognized database format 'C:\Learning\CaseMgmt.accdb'. (Microsoft JET Database Engine)